# How can I set a default image in this slide show?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, slideshow

I created a slide show using HTML and CSS only following an example I saw elsewhere. It switches photos with the hover selector. How can I get the hover to stay on permamnently until I hover to another photo? How can I set a default picture to have the hover selector active? 
Something like this example, which I can't seem to fully adapt to my code: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-hover-permanent-gallery-v2.html?

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link type="text/css"; rel="stylesheet"; href="SLideshow.css"/>
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="SlideShow">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="TheNorthFaceEcoGreen.jpg" class="Thumbnail">
      <div>
        <img src="TheNorthFaceEcoGreen.jpg" class="LargeImage">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="PuenteAcelere.jpg" class="Thumbnail">
        <div>
          <img src="PuenteAcelere.jpg" class="LargeImage">
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

With this styling:

```
<style type="text/css">
.LargeImage{width:42em; height:23.2em;border-radius:15px;}
.Thumbnail{width:10em; height:6em;}
.SlideShow{width:42em;height:33.2em;overflow:hidden; border:solid black 2px;}
.SlideShow>ul{padding:0;margin:0;}
.SlideShow>ul>li{display:inline;margin:0em;padding:0em;font-size:1em;margin-    right:-0.2em;}
.SlideShow>ul>li>div{display:none;}
.SlideShow>ul>li:hover>div{display:block;float:left;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite your code.

And I use "General sibling combinator".

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/KgV33/1/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css"; rel="stylesheet"; href="SLideshow.css"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="SlideShow">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/420x232/ccc/fff&text=1" class="Thumbnail"/>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/420x232/ccc/000&text=2" class="Thumbnail"/>
        <div class="large">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/840x464/ccc/fff&text=1" class="LargeImage"/>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/840x464/ccc/000&text=2" class="LargeImage"/>
        </div>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.LargeImage{width:42em; height:23.2em;border-radius:15px;}
.Thumbnail{width:10em; height:6em;}
.SlideShow{width:42em;height:33.2em;overflow:hidden; border:solid black 2px;}

.SlideShow > .Thumbnail ~ .large > .LargeImage{
    display:none;
}
/* default large img */
.SlideShow > .Thumbnail ~ .large > .LargeImage:nth-child(1){
    display:block;
}
/* hide all large img */
.SlideShow > .Thumbnail:hover ~ .large > .LargeImage{
    display:none;
}

.SlideShow > .Thumbnail:nth-child(2):hover ~ .large > .LargeImage:nth-child(2),
.SlideShow > .Thumbnail:nth-child(1):hover ~ .large > .LargeImage:nth-child(1){ display:block; }
```

Comment: Thankyou! It works perfectly. However I'm only starting to code html and I want to learn but I don't get the code since I'm not familiar with the use of "~". Can you please explain the function of this?

Comment: my preasure. 
please see this article. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/General_sibling_selectors